# TextView break long text into new lines

Tags: android, textview, cardview

I have a small TextView inside CardView like design. It used with as Firebase Recycler View to display content. Here its code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/main_design">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/rycImage"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rycName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:justificationMode="inter_word"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rycImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rycDesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:justificationMode="inter_word"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:lines="4"
        android:text="Desc"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rycPhone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rycImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rycName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rycMail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="e-mail"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rycImage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rycPhone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="phone"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rycMail"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/rycMail"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/rycMail" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

TextView called `rycDesc` is a long text and i want it to break into new line if it reached its margin left and right. Right now its going beyond its constrains and over ImageView. How can i make it break line after it reaches his contrains?

[image]

Comment: give full xml code , or try to increase ```android:layout_marginStart=""``` or set ```android:layout_width="your_dp"```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/rycDesc"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:justificationMode="inter_word"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:text="Desc"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rycPhone"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rycImage"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rycName" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `rycDesc`'s left and right edges are constrained you can give it a width of `0dp` so that these constraints are honored instead of `wrap_content`

Just change:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/rycDesc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
```

to

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/rycDesc"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
```

This is how it looks now:

[image]

If you are using a newer version of `ConstraintLayout` you can keep `wrap_content` and add this to `rycDesc`:

```
app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

replace with

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/rycDesc"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:text="Desc"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rycPhone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/rycImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/rycName" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 2 LinearLayout(Horizental) instead ,one for your picture and one for all your text

Answer (score 0):

Use this line inside Your TextView in xml

```
android:singleLine="false"
```